# DROP SERIES with tag key

Tags: influxdb

I am using version 1.2.1-c1.2.2 shell version

I wish to drop all series in my database where the tag value is not null.
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/query_language/database_management/#drop-series-from-the-index-with-drop-series

I ran the following query but kept getting the same error. How can I drop series using the where clause?

```
drop series from "measurement" where "tag" != ''

drop series from "measurement" where "tag" != 'abcd'
```

I got the following error

```
ERR: partial success, node 4 may be down (error code 1: fields not supported in WHERE clause during deletion)
```

How can I drop series using the WHERE clause on a key_value?